# How do I add rows summing up values only in rows that meet certain conditions

Tags: r

I have this data frame (comma-separated format here)...

```
state, sex, numerator, denominator, num_divide_denom
AL, male, 10, 20, 0.5
AL, female, 20, 30, 0.66
AL, unknown, 40, 50, 0.8
FL, male, 10, 20, 0.5
FL, female, 20, 30, 0.66
FL, unknown, 40, 50, 0.8
```

```
structure(list(state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "FL", "FL", "FL"), 
    sex = c(" male", " female", " unknown", " male", " female", 
    " unknown"), numerator = c(10L, 20L, 40L, 10L, 20L, 40L), 
    denominator = c(20L, 30L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 50L), num_divide_denom = c(0.5, 
    0.66, 0.8, 0.5, 0.66, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

How do I add rows that show, for each state, the total "numerator" and "denominator" values where "sex" is not "unknown," along with the value of (numerator / denominator) for "num_divide_denom?"

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'state', and create the column by dividing the `sum` of 'numerator' where the 'sex' is not 'unknown' with the corresponding 'denominator'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(num_divide_denom =sum(numerator[sex != 'unknown'], 
     na.rm = TRUE)/sum(denominator[sex != 'unknown'], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  state sex     numerator denominator num_divide_denom
  <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>            <dbl>
1 AL    male           10          20              0.6
2 AL    female         20          30              0.6
3 AL    unknown        40          50              0.6
4 FL    male           10          20              0.6
5 FL    female         20          30              0.6
6 FL    unknown        40          50              0.6
```

---

If we need to create new rows

```
library(janitor)
df1 %>% 
  filter(sex != 'unknown') %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  group_modify(~ adorn_totals(.x, name = 'known')) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(num_divide_denom = numerator/denominator) %>%
  bind_rows(df1 %>%
      filter(sex == 'unknown')) %>% 
      arrange(state)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  state sex     numerator denominator num_divide_denom
  <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>            <dbl>
1 AL    male           10          20            0.5  
2 AL    female         20          30            0.667
3 AL    known          30          50            0.6  
4 AL    unknown        40          50            0.8  
5 FL    male           10          20            0.5  
6 FL    female         20          30            0.667
7 FL    known          30          50            0.6  
8 FL    unknown        40          50            0.8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "FL", "FL", "FL"), 
    sex = c("male", "female", "unknown", "male", "female", "unknown"
    ), numerator = c(10L, 20L, 40L, 10L, 20L, 40L), denominator = c(20L, 
    30L, 50L, 20L, 30L, 50L), num_divide_denom = c(0.5, 0.66, 
    0.8, 0.5, 0.66, 0.8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~bind_rows(
      .x,
      tibble(
        sex = 'known',
        numerator = sum(.x$numerator[.x$sex != 'unknown']),
        denominator = sum(.x$denominator[.x$sex != 'unknown']),
        num_divide_denom = numerator / denominator
      )
    )
  )
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 × 5
> # Groups:   state [2]
>   state sex     numerator denominator num_divide_denom
>   <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>            <dbl>
> 1 AL    male           10          20             0.5 
> 2 AL    female         20          30             0.66
> 3 AL    unknown        40          50             0.8 
> 4 AL    known          30          50             0.6 
> 5 FL    male           10          20             0.5 
> 6 FL    female         20          30             0.66
> 7 FL    unknown        40          50             0.8 
> 8 FL    known          30          50             0.6
> ```

Or

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(
    numerator = sum(numerator[sex != 'unknown']),
    denominator = sum(denominator[sex != 'unknown']),
    sex = 'known',
    num_divide_denom = numerator / denominator
  ) %>% bind_rows(df1)
```